# Conditional Statements JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So I have a very basic conditional statement but I am trying to get a different answer. I want to have a default command of else that if a user is inputting something greater than 10 that they get an alert of "the numbers are only from 1-10" what is a way I can do this?

```
var number = 7;
var stringGuess = prompt("guess a number");
var guess = Number(stringGuess);



if (guess === number) {
    alert("you got it");
}

else if(guess > 10) {
    alert(" Too High Guess Lower");
}

else if (guess < number) {
    alert("Too low guess higher!");
}
else {

}
```

Comment: you would check `if(guess > 10)` - which you already do, but you never `if(guess > number)` which is odd

Comment: well thats the thing I'm trying to mess around with it but even if I use guess > than the var number it still gives me the same answer. I am trying to have an else statement that only tracks number 1-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified a little bit of your code:
I used `switch` for the conditions which basically judge if `guess` is matching the `number` or below or above. Then add `txt` as extra information if the `guess` is out of `1-10`.

```js
var number = 7;
var stringGuess = prompt("guess a number");
var guess = Number(stringGuess);

switch ( true ) {
  case ( guess === number ):
    alert('You got it!');
    break;
  case ( guess > number ):
    var txt = ( guess > 10 ) ? ' and the number is smaller than 10' : '';
    alert( 'Too high' + txt );
    break;
  case ( guess < number ):
    var txt = ( guess < 1 ) ? ' and the number greater than 1' : '';
    alert( 'Too low' + txt );
    break;
}
```

You can try this and they do exactly the same thing by using `IF ELSE`.

```js
var number = 7;
var stringGuess = prompt("guess a number");
var guess = Number(stringGuess);
var txt = ( guess > 10 ) ? ' and the number is smaller than 10' : '';
if ( guess < 1 ) txt = ' and the number greater than 1';

if ( guess === number ) {
  alert('You got it!');
} else if ( guess > number ) {
  alert( 'Too high' + txt );
} else {
  alert( 'Too low' + txt );
}
```

Comment: hey thanks I was looking to see if there was another operator or different method but this works too! Do you know if this only possible in a switch statement? Or could I implement this in an if else statement.

Comment: @PeterTran, I edited the answer. If you like the answer please upvote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a good case for breaking things into functions, in order to hide the how, and talk about the what it is you're trying to accomplish.

```
function isInBounds (low, x, high) { return low <= x && x <= high; }
function isAnswer (x, number) { return x === number; }
function gt (x, number) { return x > number; }

function generateRandomInt (floor, ceiling) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (ceiling - floor)) + floor;
}


var lowerBound = 1;
var upperBound = 10;


// the +1 is because Random will never, ever be equal to the high number
// so a random number between 1 and 10 really means between 1 and 11
var answer = getRandomInt(lowerBound, upperBound + 1);
var successMessage = "You got it!";
var failureMessage = "Guess again!";
var errorMessage = "Error: guess must be a number between "
  + lowerBound + " and " + upperBound + ".";

function checkGuess (x) {
  var message = "";
  if (isInBounds(lowerBound, x, upperBound)) {
    message = isAnswer(x, answer) ? successMessage : failureMessage;
  } else {
    message = errorMessage;
  }
  alert(message);
}
```

I'm using ternary assignment to set the value of `message`.

```
var x = isTrue ? truthyValue : falseyValue;
```

You can even nest these on the truthy or falsey paths.

```
var result = a ? x : b ? y : z;
// if a == true, x, else if b == true, y, else z
```

That said, you may want to be careful with that setup.